# ¿Como puedo crear animaciones de sprites en un juego "grid-based" en love2d?

Tags: lua, love2d

Estoy creando un juego de pokemon desde 0 y quiero crear el estilo de movimiento de personajes que tiene.

Los cuadrados de los tilesets del mapa son 32x32, y los del personaje 32x48. Por tanto, para moverlo se necesita sumar a la X o Y del personaje 32 píxeles. Hasta aquí fácil, pero la cosa se complica cuando queremos animar la sprite del personaje. En este caso tenemos al profesor Oak. Su tileset nos muestra como debe tener 4 frames para los 4 movimientos básicos, arriba, abajo, izquierda y derecha.

Ante este problema, decidí programarlo de tal forma que cada 8 píxeles de movimiento wasd, usando `love.keyboard.isDown`, mostrara el frame correspondiente de cada uno de sus movimientos. El problema sale a la luz. Cada vez que se presiona una de esas teclas, solo hace el movimiento de 8 píxeles, y se queda en el siguiente frame. Es decir, para que haga el recorrido de una casilla entera, se ha de apretar 4 veces la misma tecla.

La cuestión es que haga el movimiento de 8 píxeles 4 veces seguidas, sin que el usuario pueda apretar ninguna tecla hasta que se complete el movimiento de 32 píxeles, evitando múltiples errores de elección de fotograma incorrecto, e impidiendo el movimiento no encasillado.

Intenté hacerlo con bucles `for`, pero no dibuja bien en la función `love.draw()`, cosa lógica la verdad.

Os paso el código entero por one drive: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvRWkdEmuSbYg0UOdQN9P2CBcIuS

Espero que haya alguna función de love que pueda usar para hacer esto de forma optimizada. Si no funciona por culpa de la forma en que está programado, estoy abierto a modificaciones.

Comment: Dentro de la comunidad love 2D han abordado este caso y han provisto una solución y archivos sobre el particular, los cuales podrás correrlos en tu ordenador ya que tienes instalado el citado SDK. Lo anterior lo puedes encontrar en este **[post](https://www.love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=50336)**

Answer (score 0):

Hace 2 años de la pregunta pero bueno...
Lo que hago es simplemente obligar a que cada vez que presiones una tecla para moverte, el sprite haga las cuatro animaciones que tienes.
Esta es la parte del código que tienes que cambiar:

```
function muevePj(dt)
elapsed = elapsed + dt
    if elapsed > 0.1 then
        elapsed = elapsed - 0.1

        if love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
            down = true
        end
        if down == true then
            if currentFrame == 4 then
                currentFrame = 1
                down = false           --Hasta que no pasa por todas 
                                       --las fases, down no vuelve a false
            elseif currentFrame < 4 then

                currentFrame = currentFrame + 1
            end
            initPosY = initPosY + 8
        end

    end
```

end

Comment: Podrias mirar [answer]. Las respuestas que son solo codigo, se consideran de baja calidad